# How do I force Ubuntu to detect a microphone even when it is not plugged?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, budgie

My microphone jack was not working, so I removed it and soldered a small mic directly onto the board (silly me!). Now, my computer does not detect a microphone, but catches the signal. It can be seen in the below screenshot.
So, my computer is getting the signal, but now I need to force it to detect that I've inserted a microphone.
Is there any way that I can 'fool' my computer, so that it detects a mic even when I've not inserted a mic in the jack?